# When filtering a character vector in data.table, it also removes the NA values.. what's the logic in this?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I recently  had to count a charactervector, and I encountered the following, which seems like a bug to me, but then again, it's so simple it could be a desired behaviour - although I have no idea why you would want this behaviour.

here, I create a DT, filter everything but the NAs and count them. everything's good.

```
library(data.table)

test1 <- data.table(v1=c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5),rep(NA,5)))
test1[is.na(v1), .(n_NA= .N), .(v1)]
```

in test2, I filter all values of 'A'. BUT, data.table as also removed the NAs.

```
test2 <- test1[v1!='A']
test2[is.na(v1), .(n_NA= .N), .(v1)]
```

It's only if I explicitly tells data.table to keep the NAs that it does so.

```
test3 <- test1[!v1=='A' | is.na(v1)]
test3[is.na(v1), .(n_NA= .N), .(v1)]
```

now, base R does the same thing in the which() function, but not in the logical vector that returns TRUE FALSE

```
test4 <- as.data.frame(test1)
    test4[test4$v1!='B',]       
test4[which(test4$v1!='B'),]
```

And dplyr does the same - that is, removes the NAs.

```
dplyr::filter(test1, v1!='A')
```

So I guess there must be some sense to it. But I just don't get it. I'm explicitly stating that I want anything BUT 'A', and the default behaviour is to remove the NAs as well? Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When R tests `NA != "A"`, it returns `NA` instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE`. When you try to subset a data.table with NA values in the vector, it simply removes it.

You can try using `%in%`. Examples:

```
NA %in% "A" #FALSE
NA %in% NA #TRUE
"B" %in% "A" #FALSE
"B" %in% "BA" #FALSE
"B" %in% "B" #TRUE
```

And for your particular example:

```
library(data.table)
test1 <- data.table(v1=c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5),rep(NA,5)))
test1[!(v1 %in% "A")]
# Output: data.table of one column v1 with 5 Bs and 5 NAs
```